# Using an If condition inside a template

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

How do you use an `IF` statement inside of a jQuery template?

Here's my template:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="attachmentListTemplate">
{{if $item.current_cmt_id == id }}
    <li>
        <a href="${link}" class="fancyIFrame clearfix">${title}</a>
    </li>
{{/if}}
</script>
```

Where id is essentially `${id}` and is being passed by the data binding (via KnockoutJS). Which without an IF statement outputs fine, like so: `${$item.current_cmt_id}`

Here is the data-binding (powered by KnockoutJS):

```html
<ul data-bind='template: { name: "attachmentListTemplate", foreach: attachmentsModel.convAttachments, templateOptions: {current_cmt_id: <%=comment.id%>} }'> </ul>
```

Any suggestions as to why the if sttatement is not working? Am I comparing the two conditions correctly?

Comment: You using server side language too?  If so, is the source showing an integer?  (because of the <%=comment.id%> i ask...)

Comment: ya it is, that would render in the browsers as an INT, 111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is an observable, you need to invoke it as a function rather than treat is as a property. Try the following:

```
{{if $item.current_cmt_id == id()}}
```

Comment: That did it! You are my hero - Thank you!

Comment: Good call, this can be tough to track down!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to surround the <%=comment.id%> with quotes?

```
        <ul data-bind='template: { name: "attachmentListTemplate", foreach: attachmentsModel.convAttachments, templateOptions: {current_cmt_id: "<%=comment.id%>"} }'> </ul>
```

Comment: nope that's work just fine. something with jQuery Template, I don't know how to do the conditional

Comment: I have seen seen some template systems use <% %> as the placeholder so I was wondering if that was it too.  Guess not.